# Google drive export API not creating the xlxs extension

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using google drive export API to download a google sheet to Microsoft excel format.

It does exports the file but it does not have an extension of .xlsx . But the same export from google docs UI does the export with extension.

I am using the below code

```
 driveService.files().export(createdFile.getId(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet").executeAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

How can i export the file and get the Microsoft excel extension ?

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: What is `executeAndDownloadTo`?

Comment: @Tanaike executeAndDownloadTo executes the command and downloads it to the output stream specified

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I see the script of `executeAndDownloadTo`?

Comment: They are part of Google Drive Java APIs

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, can I ask you about your goal? Which language do you want to use Java or Node.js?

Comment: I use java and my goal is to export the google sheets into Microsoft excel with extension

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, when you want to achieve your goal using Java, how about modifying the tags? In your tags, I had thought that you might want to achieve your goal using Node.js.

Comment: I did not do it...someone  did the edit...may be the code was not clear enough

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your goal, when you want to achieve your goal using Java, how about also adding the tag of `java`?

Answer (score 0):

The Files.export method you are trying to use allows Google Workspace documents to be downloaded as stated in the [`documentation`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export):

You could try using the sample code found in the Drive API [sample documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads#download_a_document):

```
/**
 * Download a Document file in Excel format
 * @param{string} fileId file ID
 * @return{obj} file status
 * */
async function exportPdf(fileId) {
  const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');
  const {google} = require('googleapis');

  // Get credentials and build service
  // TODO (developer) - Use appropriate auth mechanism for your app
  const auth = new GoogleAuth({scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'});
  const service = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});

  try {
    const result = await service.files.export({
      fileId: fileId,
      mimeType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    });
    console.log(result.status);
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    // TODO(developer) - Handle error
    throw err;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes...i have used this ...but this does not export with an extension